# Dump empty line with proper formatting in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have a dict

```
{"a": ""}
```

and when I dump it in ruamel.yaml it appears like this:

```
a: ''
```

I tried dumping

```
{"a": None}
```

instead and got

```
a:<no space>
```

How can I get

```
a:<one space>
```

so that I can input into the yaml file immediately?